# Open XML support in Pages

Tags: macos, pages, iwork, xml

It looks like iWork's Pages supports Open XML - however, I can't find any good information on this on either developer.apple.com or on the web. Is there a good resource for this that I'm not aware of? I see http://openxmldeveloper.org but this is clearly MS-specific. Is there a comparable resource for Pages?

I'd like a trivial example of how this would work such as a "Hello World" type document. Does this exist?

Answer (score 2):

Office Open XML is a standard invented by Microsoft - their documentation would be the go-to resource. Pages simply uses the built-in OS X ability to read them. TextEdit can read OOXML (i.e. .docx) as well, and is included (with source) with Apple's developer tools as a sample.

Comment: i have found a lot of discrepancies in layouts with textedit and ooxml making it essentially useless

Comment: @timpone That might be more TextEdit's display engine than the document parser. What are you trying to do with OOXML, anyway? If you're writing a reader/writer, this question would be better served over at Stack Overflow.

Comment: not looking at all to write a reader / parser. I'd like to output openxml that could be used to either a word doc or an apple pages doc. An example 'hello world' would be an ideal starting place

Comment: @timpone So you're looking to make a program that writes OOXML. Your best bet is to ask on Stack Overflow (link here if you think it'll be helpful), to check out Apple's docs about the document I/O options (maybe they have a writer built into the Cocoa framework), and to look at Microsoft's docs on the spec if you want to write your own writer. If you get really ambitious, you could also look at the official ISO standards document.